# How to insert record to mysql database during backup?

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, backup

Currently I got 2 method to backup database

1. WebBrowser > http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ > Select DB > Export
2. Application built-in backup function

If I use method 1 I can still insert record to database during backup, if I use method 2 I will get this error:-

> An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException'
>   occurred in MySql.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: There is already an open DataReader associated
>   with this Connection which must be closed first.

Below is backup function code:-

```
  Private Sub BackgroundWorker_DoWork(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)

    If CheckField("Backup") Then
        Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand
        cmd.Connection = conn
        Dim mb As MySqlBackup = New MySqlBackup(cmd)

        Dim filename As String = tb_filename.Text & IIf(chkb_currDate.Checked, $" {DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")}", "")
        Dim path As String = tb_backupPath.Text

        mb.ExportToFile($"{path}{filename}.sql")

        MessageBox.Show($"Successfully backup to {path}", "Tips", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End If
End Sub
```

How can I insert record to database during backup if I want to use method 2?

Comment: It means you already have a reader open somewhere else in your application. So make sure you close it after using it. The best is to implement the `USING` method for every `IDisposable`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement

Comment: @Mederic sorry i still don't know how to solve it, I guess the backup process will open a reader and close it after finish backup, so I can't run other function which need to call the reader during backup. So I should not use background worker for backup process unless I can solve this problem? because most of the function in this application will need to open the reader.

Comment: remember you can only have one datareader connected to the database at the same time. This is why you should simply: `create, open, use, dispose` as fast as possible and as fast as possible don't leave other connections open as long you don't need them if you do this in an efficient way you should be able do your backup easily.